# GLUT blank screen when entering full screen (glutEnterGamemode())

Tags: opengl, shader, glut

I have been using GLUT & OpenGL to develop a 3D FPS. I have made an option to go into full screen but when I click this the screen goes blank. I am using shaders and #version 150 so I must use: GLUT_3_2_CORE_PROFILE in my glutInitDisplayMode:

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_3_2_CORE_PROFILE);
```

If I take GLUT_3_2_CORE_PROFILE out of the code the error is no longer existent but my shaders do not work. 
This is the main code in my main.cpp:

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
glutInitWindowSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
glutCreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_3_2_CORE_PROFILE);
```

How do I fix this issue? Do I need to change the order of anything?

Comment: Which GLUT implementation are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you forgot to call `glutGameModeString`, like `glutGameModeString("1024x768:32");` before entering game mode.